explanation for density order in group 2 elements
In Group 1 (alkali metals), density generally increases as you move down the group. However, in Group 2 (alkaline earth metals), the density might decrease initially and then increase. So when we compare the densities of group 2 elements, is there a visible rule/trend? Specifically, what causes the irregularity in the density trend amongst group 2 elements?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57484/why-alkali-metals-have-bcc-structure

Elements within the same group (column) of the periodic table exhibit trends in various properties, including density. Group 1 (alkali metals) demonstrates an increase in density as we move down the group. This can be attributed to the increasing atomic mass, which outweighs the increase in atomic radius due to additional electron shells. However, Group 2 (alkaline earth metals) you cannot really say that there is a generalised trend(or a gradient in its physical properties).
The higher density of Group 2 elements compared to Group 1 elements can be explained by their greater charge density(greater nuclear charge and smaller size). This results from a combination of a stronger positive nuclear charge attracting the valence electrons and a generally smaller atomic size in Group 2. This allows for a more efficient packing of cations in the metallic lattice, leading to a denser arrangement.
Within Group 2 itself, the density trend exhibits an irregularity. Initially, from beryllium to calcium, there might be a slight decrease in density. This can be attributed to the increasing atomic radius initially outweighing the mass increase. However, this is followed by a considerable rise in density. Here, the effect of larger mass becomes more dominant, leading to a denser packing despite the increasing atomic radii.
The observed irregularity in Group 2 density can also be ascribed to the influence of crystal structure. Different alkaline earth metals can adopt various crystal packing arrangements, impacting the overall density. For instance, beryllium (Be) exhibits a hexagonal close-packed structure, while calcium (Ca) adopts a face-centered cubic crystal structure, thus calcium has a lower density. Strontium (Sr) has a cubic closest-packed structure, thus it has a higher density than calcium and beryllium. These variations in crystal packing can contribute to the observed deviations(at room temperature).
